# How to make two Django models with cross relationship?

Tags: python, django, django-models

I need two Django models: first with **Users**, second with **Projects**.

Between them I need many-to-many relationship with an additional field(s).

How to make the below code working?

```
from django.db import models

class User(models.Model):

    name = models.CharField('Name', max_length=50)
    projects = models.ManyToManyField(Project, through='UserProjects')

    def __str__(self):
        return self.name

class Project(models.Model):

    name = models.CharField('Name', max_length=50)
    users = models.ManyToManyField(User, through='UserProjects')

    def __str__(self):
        return self.name

class UserProjects(models.Model):

    user = models.ForeignKey(User)
    project = models.ForeignKey(Project)
    is_active = models.BooleanField('Active')
```

At the end **User.projects** should return **Projects** for specified **User**
and in the same way **Project.users** should return **Users** for specified **Project**.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
from django.db import models

class User(models.Model):

    name = models.CharField('Name', max_length=50)

    def __str__(self):
        return self.name

class Project(models.Model):

    name = models.CharField('Name', max_length=50)
    users = models.ManyToManyField(User, through='UserProjects', related_name='projects')

    def __str__(self):
        return self.name

class UserProjects(models.Model):

    user = models.ForeignKey(User)
    project = models.ForeignKey(Project)
    is_active = models.BooleanField('Active')
```

Answer (score 1):

There's no need to put the m2m field on both sides
 Jussi pick one, and Django will automatically create a reverse relationship for the other direction.

Comment: I know - but need this for clear and nice application interface

Comment: @pga Well, it won't work with Django. If it sees two M2M declarations, it thinks there are 2 different M2M relations. If you're talking about admin interface for the reverse relationship, you'll have to add it when you set [your admin options](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/ref/contrib/admin/#working-with-many-to-many-models)

Answer (score -1):

Here is the simplest solution in my opinion:

```
from django.db import models

class User(models.Model):

    name = models.CharField('Name', max_length=50)


class Project(models.Model):

    name = models.CharField('Name', max_length=50)


class UserProjects(models.Model):

    user = models.ForeignKey(User, related_name='projects')
    project = models.ForeignKey(Project, related_name='users')
    is_active = models.BooleanField('Active')
```

In above **User.projects** returns **Projects** for specified User and also **Project.users** returns **Users** for specified Project.